# Axis locking will not work

Tags: transforms, axis

When I select an object, press <kbd>G</kbd> ,<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> and then an axis shortcut <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, the object does not lock to the axis.

I select an object - Works as expected.
I press a transform key, gizmo changes as expected.
I press an axis shortcut e.g. <kbd>Z</kbd> I get the shading radial menu.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could be an issue with your key mappings. Have you looked at your settings? Try going to Edit->Preferences->Keymap->3D View->3D View (Global)->Move->Transform Modal Map (long path, I know), there should be three entries that say something like 'X axis / X'.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up loading factory settings to resolve this.